# Double/Stacked Donut Chart - translucent border between arcs

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I would like to achieve the following illustration with translucent borders/spacing in JS/CSS:

[image: Double Dounut]

As far as I have come I have found a simple solution using the Chart.JS library. I have added multiple data sets, configured a custom border color and an custom border width to get the right spacing.

I dont know, how to remove the border color and set a translucent border. rgba(x,y,z,0) do not work because it removes the border itself. Furthermore the top ring also have an (unwanted) border. Does someone have any advice for Chart.JS or a solution with an other library?

```
    var config = {
     type: 'doughnut',
     data: {
       datasets: [{
         data: [..],
         backgroundColor: [...],
         borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
         borderWidth: 10
       }, {
         data: [...],
         backgroundColor: [...],
         borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
         borderWidth: 10       }],
       labels: [...]
     },
     options: {...}
   };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zrdd4ur8/

---

**Update 1**

I was able to establish the spacing between the outer Ring and the inner rings without any border as seen in the below picture. To do so you need to modify the source of Chart.js around line 9876. It should look like the following:

```
 draw: function() {

 var ctx = this._chart.ctx,
     vm = this._view,
     sA = vm.startAngle,
     eA = vm.endAngle;

 ctx.beginPath();

 // here I set a 10px spacing
 ctx.arc(vm.x, vm.y, vm.outerRadius - 10, sA, eA);
 ctx.arc(vm.x, vm.y, vm.innerRadius + 10, eA, sA, true);

 // console.log(vm.backgroundColor);
 // console.log("X: " + vm.x + " Y: " + vm.y + " Outer: " + vm.outerRadius + " Inner: " + vm.innerRadius + " sA: " + sA + " eA: " + eA)

 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
 ctx.lineWidth = vm.borderWidth;

 ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;

 ctx.fill();
 ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';


 if (vm.borderWidth) {
     ctx.stroke();
 }
 }
```

I'm sure that it's possible to achieve the spacing between the arcs here, too. But my mathematics are not well enough at this moment.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Are you ok with a white border, or you specifically want transparent?

Comment: Taking any advice you can provide. The goal is to place the chart on any background without seen borders.

Comment: I played around with the chart a little and it seems like the Chart.js canvas is first drawing a complete background, and then putting the border color on top. If you set the border colors to transparent, the background color, here green, is just showing through. I would suggest just commenting out the `borderColor` line for now, so it defaults to the white `#fff` background. I don't know if it is possible to make the background under the borders also transparent with Chart.js.

Comment: Thank you that was a good hint, I updated my question.